# Ternary operator always false despite state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with a ternary operator in React, which is used inside a component to render content A or B depending on the state (passed as a prop).
The ternary operator seems to always turn out false (null content), even when the prop/state changes.
Here is the code :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      activeFooter: false
    }

    this.toggleFooter = this.toggleFooter.bind(this);
  }

    toggleFooter() {
      console.log("toggleFooter !")
      this.setState({ activeFooter: !this.state.activeFooter })

    }

render() {  
 return (

 (...)

<Container className="footerContainer">
        <Row>
        <Col xs="12">

          <StickyFooter
            bottomThreshold={75}
            normalStyles={{
              backgroundColor:"#000",
              width:"100%",
            }}
            stickyStyles={{
              width:"100%",
              backgroundColor:"#000",
              color:"chartreuse",
              opacity:"1",
              borderTopColor: "#05ff57",
              borderWidth: "1px 0 0 0",
              borderStyle:"solid",
            }}
            fullFooter = {this.state.activeFooter}
            onFooterStateChange={this.toggleFooter}
            >

              {this.props.fullFooter ? (
              <div>
               <Row className="footer">
                <Col className="footerCol" xs="4">
                  <ContactModal className="modalContact"/>
                </Col>
                <Col className="footerCol" xs="4">
                  <i className="fas fa-arrow-up" onClick={this.scrollToTop}/>
                </Col>
                <Col className="footerCol"  xs="4">
                  <i className="fas fa-map-marker-alt"/>
                </Col>
              </Row></div> ) : null }

          </StickyFooter>

          </Col>
        </Row>
          </Container>
)
};
```

I'm guessing this is a problem with my ternary operator syntax and me being a bit newbish, but I fear it might be a more complex problem (re-rendering, component update not fired, or something along those lines.)

Thanks in advance for any answer or nudge in the right direction !

Comment: You have two flags `activeFooter & fullFooter` which one doesnt work?

Comment: Your component is referring to `this.props.fullFooter`. Why not just `this.state.activeFooter`?

Comment: Your " ternary operator syntax" is ok. The problem is that you are mixing flags: the one you are controlling in App's state `this.state.activeFooter` and the one that has to come via App's props `this.props.fullFooter`. `StickyFooter` children are rendered by App, I bet you should use `this.state.activeFooter`

Comment: `this.props.fullFooter` is a result of me fooling around to find a solution. Even when using `{ this.state.activeFooter ? contentA : contentNull }`, the content of the footer is never updated and stays `null`